# MEF loading plugins from a network shared folder

Tags: c#, mef

Tearing my hair out trying to work out why Im having this problem so hope someone can help.

I have a program that uses MEF to load plugins. I would like the client and server part of the system to be able to use the same plugin store that will be located on the server.

My problem is that when I set the plugin location to "`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientPlugins`" the plugin is loaded fine. If I change the location to "`\\XRP-SERVER\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientPlugins`" the plugin is not loaded.

When I enter "`\\XRP-SERVER\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientPlugins`" into windows explorer the location is found and the plugin dll is there.

Please could someone help.

Let me know if you require anymore information.

As per a suggestion I have tried editing the config to include the following but this has not fixed the issues....

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
      </runtime>
```

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem yesterday and narrowed the problem down to how MEF loads assemblies.
When you create a DirectoryCatalog, it in turns creates a collection of AssemblyCatalogs.
Each AssemblyCatalog does an:

```
    AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssembly();
    Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
```

The call to `Assembly.Load` throws a sandbox Exception (for a reason I can't explain yet) and therefore no parts are found since it silently catches the error.

The funny thing is that calling `Assembly.LoadFrom(<pathToYourDll>)` to return an `Assembly` works fine (no exception is thrown). Combine that with the overloaded constructor of `AssemblyCatalog` that takes an `Assembly` as its input and you got yourself a workaround!

So instead of using a `DirectoryCatalog`, I list all the DLLs in the path and iteratively create an `AssemblyCatalog` and add it to my `CompositionContainer`.

Note : I am using the loadFromRemoteSources="true" flag in my App.Config and it is required, otherwise it always crashes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Im in the process of trying this and am with you right upto the point where you add the AssemblyCatalog to the CompositionContainer. I cant see an add method on the CompositionContainer. COuld you explain this bit a little more please?

Comment: Its ok I worked out you need to create an aggregateCatalogue then add your assemblyCataglogues to it then add your aggregateCatalogue to the compositionContainer.

Comment: Please let me know if you find out why this works and the standard method doesnt :) I daresay Microsoft would be interested in knowing aswell :) Thanks again for the answer :)

Comment: I looked through Reflector but couldn't find the reason why. I guess it has to do with the differences in context between Load and LoadFrom (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx)). Since my last answer, I also found that LoadFrom may be dangerous and I ran into this problem [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/74319.aspx) : loading twice the same DLL is possible with LoadFrom and results in weird behaviors. You have to be rigorous if you are going to use LoadFrom :)

Answer (score 8):

Security policies will typically disable loading remote code (that being, assemblies on an external location).

You can try the following config change:

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

The other thing to be aware of is when you are copying files back from network locations, they will typically have a Zone specified in their alternate data stream. In explorer, this can be removed by using the "Unblock" command when viewing the properties of a file.

Alternatively, you could programatically remove the Zone from the alternate data stream, as shown [here on Mike Hadlow's blog](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/07/mef-directorycatalog-fails-to-load.html).

Comment: When I saw this my eyes lit up as I thought it would work. Doesnt look like it has done though :( I have placed this in the config and it still wont load when using the '\\XRP-SERVER\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientPlugins' path. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify sebd's answer works.

Heres the final code I used.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ClientPluginStore, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

AggregateCatalog aggCat = new AggregateCatalog();

aggCat.Catalogs.Add(catalog);

foreach ( string file in files )
{
    Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

    AssemblyCatalog assCat = new AssemblyCatalog(ass);

    aggCat.Catalogs.Add(assCat);
}

_container = new CompositionContainer(aggCat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.IO.Path.PathSeparator instead of \?

Or may be fetch the file to client location first?

I'm not pretty sure about them, but I would give it a try.

Comment: Thanks I'll try the path seperator. A future task is to stream the plugin from the server via wcf if the client doesnt have access to the shared location. I want to get the shared location working first and want to understand why it isnt :)

Comment: Another thing is, when I think on it: using "file://"?

Comment: I have checked that I am supplying the path in format the C# can read.
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\XRP-SERVER\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\ClientPlugins", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
           
Console.WriteLine(fCount);

This returns 1 which is the plugin dll

Comment: so, the backslashes is the answer?